# condition ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to iterate rows for table

```
 <td ng-repeat=" (col,row) in rows" ng-if=="col?'IP_ADDRESS' row:'<a>row</a>'">
            {{row}}
 </td>
```

What i am looking for is when col value is IP_ADDRESS the 'row' should be returned wrapped in anchor tag.
Is this even possible

sample data  is

```
{"IP_ADDRESS":"10.10.10.10","MACHINE":"mymachine"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using `ng-if` incorrectly. `ng-if` will insert the elements HTML its applied to if the condition is truthy, otherwise it will remove it. It does not inject content into the existing HTML.

so maybe (not tested)

```
<td ng-repeat="(col,row) in rows">
    <a ng-if="row === IP_ADDRESS" >{{row}}</a>
    <span ng-if="row !== IP_ADDRESS" >{{row}}</span>
 </td>
```

see docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) is what you are looking for.

```
<td ng-repeat="(col,row) in rows">
    <span ng-bind-html="getHtml(row,col) | to_trusted"></span>
</td>
```

with this in your *.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

myApp.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.getHtml = function(row, col) {
      return col == "IP" ? '<a href="">' + row + '</a>' : row;
    };
}]);
```

this way you have more control over editing the HTML.

Comment: You should be careful editing your HTML like that in your controller. +1 for using `ng-bind-html` over jQuery etc however that is not behavior your controller should be doing, or at least not your main page controller. It should be juggling your services, directives, events etc. You could extract it out into a separate controller for that specific functionality (monolith controllers are just as bad). Or even better a directive.

Comment: @ste2425 You're right! For demonstration reasons I also could have inlined it, but i think for understanding, this is the shortest way. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fm2HqxeCfLUH6gAs5Ea9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td ng-repeat=" row in rows">
        <div ng-if="row == 'IP_ADDRESS'">{{row.yourValue}}</div>
        <div ng-if="row != 'IP_ADDRESS'">{{row.yourOtherValue}}</div>
</td>
```

inside "yourValue" your anchor tag could be defined. I have no structure of "rows" so i tried to simplify it for the logic. hope it helps ;)